# When run avahi-daemon on arm linux board, it report below log and quited

Tags: avahi

After cross complied avahi-0.8 and pull it into my arm-linux board, then run avahi-daemon, it report below log info:
root@NVTEVM:/mnt/data$ avahi-daemon
Found user 'root' (UID 0) and group 'root' (GID 0).
Failed to change group list: Function not implemented

and then quit.

what is happen and how to solve it?

More: Avahi build without GLIB and DBUS.

1. ARM linux is based on ARM9 and Nor flash (jffs2)

Answer (score 0):

Check your filesystem attribute can't be readonly, Most of cases define in bootargs transfer by u-boot/uefi